# How do I create an instance of a controller for each instance of a view in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I'm creating a widget/component that can be referenced several times in the same template with the #view-helper. Example:

```
Priority: {{view App.DropDown valueBinding="content.priority" sourceBinding="App.Priority"}} <br/>
Status: {{view App.DropDown valueBinding="content.status" sourceBinding="App.Status"}} <br/>
```

This widget needs to communicate with the store to get the list of all the visible items. As I understand Ember, views should not communicate with the store directly. Is it possible to create an instance of my DropDownController for each view?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good fit for the control helper. This instantiates a new Controller everytime you use it:

```
Priority: {{control "dropDown" valueBinding="content.priority" sourceBinding="App.Priority"}} <br/>
Status: {{control "dropDown" valueBinding="content.status" sourceBinding="App.Status"}} <br/>
```

This snippet should instantiate each time a fresh DropDownController and DropDownView upon call. You just need to figure out, what is the best way to pass the value and sourceBinding to your view.

Comment: This looks like it will solve my problem. Stand by for verification :)

Comment: I will. Tell me your solution, so that i can update the bindings accordingly for other people. :-)

Comment: It looks like the {{control}}-helper doesn't work with Bindings, so I can't use it. If this issue was resolved, it will work for my scenario: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2225

Comment: But you could try this: {{control "dropDown" content.priority}}. All you need to do is guess the right source from the passed object, right?

Comment: How do you create fiddles with experimental features?
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_control

Comment: Place it in the ready code of your application would be good i guess. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#event_ready

Comment: `{{control "dropDown" content.priority}}` will assign the `content.priority` to the `model` property of the controller. BUT this is not a binding... an observer will be created that will cause the view to be recreated when that property changes. It would be better to use `{{control "dropDown" content}}` and handle specifying the individual property elsewhere. Any bindings in the helper should get passed to the view, ultimately, so the appropriate binding should be `valueBinding="model.priority"`